# Hybris - exporting a content page via in ImpEx script

Tags: export, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Does anybody know if it is possible to export hybris content pages (created in CMS cockpit) using an ImpEx script? I've found some documentation (although not official) online [here](http://www.jhalabi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Hybris-Create-components-via-IMPEX-files.pdf) that describes creating a new page using something like the following:

```
INSERT_UPDATE 
ContentPage;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;masterTemplate(uid,$cont
entCV);label;defaultPage[default='true'];approvalStatus(code)[default='approved'];
homepage[default='false'];previewImage(code, 
$contentCV)[default='ContentPageModel__function_preview']
;;about;About Us;ContentPage2Template;/about
```

I was wondering if there is a way to export a page using something similar? I'm very new to hybris so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may export any entity/model with ImpEx. Just run correct script. Please use *System->Tools->Script Generator* from hMC to generate script for all DB entities. Search for DB table that is appropriate for your needs and run it snippet at *System->Tools->Export*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be more specific as to what are you trying to achieve.
As far as your question goes

> if it is possible to export hybris content pages (created in CMS
>   cockpit) using an ImpEx script?

answer is yes it is possible.Impex script that you have written is also alright.
So in hybris your content pages (created from cms cockpit) are of type "ContentPage".
And this type contains some optional and mandatory attributes like uid,template etc. that define the look and content of the page.
Impex are a way to import(export script are there also) data into the type in this case "ContentPage".

For more you can ckeckout [HybrisHub](http://www.hybrishub.com/)

Comment: Thanks @sameer. For clarity, I'm putting together a series of scripts that will allow me to capture a selection of data in hybris for migration between environments - one piece of this data is the content pages. You're answer has provided enough for me to begin work on this - I'll raise follow up questions if I have any issues with Impex. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi danw I have your same question. Could you please provide me your impex files? I would export in impex file the mobile pages. Thank you very much